# how to access RESTful parameters from ZK GenericForwardComposer when using Spring MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, jakarta-ee, zk, restful-url

i'm working on a project using zk and spring.Basically Spring manages object life-cycle of the objects.i've planned to use cute url.for that i used ZK MVC pattern and added Spring 3 MVC front controller by mapping the requests to the views using `mvc:view-controller`

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>
```

There has been a situation where i would need to access parameters from the cute url (RESTful)
but i couldn't find how to use that.I think also that my fear is to complicate the whole project my mixing the 2 MVC patterns.I posted [here](http://jp.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/16338;jsessionid=E1BDF0154DD3575A2E3A24E07D2B094A.zkzh) on ZK forun but i got no answer so far.I ended up using `session` for parameter passing.

Is there any way to do that? how would you do that?

thanks for reading.

Comment: anyone? :( i really need a strategy or an idea to work around that.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ZEST](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZEST%20Essentials/Quick%20Start/Overview) yet? My understanding is you can use ZEST for beautifying your urls to ZUML/JSP pages and let ZK MVC take care of the Ajax events.